# Logging framework for C++

Tags: c++, logging

I apologize to take a topic which is widely discussed before - but I find none of the discussions clearly tell which one to use ultimately. My requirements for a logging framework in my C++ project are

1. Thread safe.
2. Should support multiple targets.
3. Log rotation possible.
4. A way to identify module's implicitly.

I have been using boost log for some time in a small c++ project and it worked well. But when I took to a large C++ project - I found supporting multiple targets(I mean multiple files for the same project) is a nightmare, No way to implicitly mention which module is logging and above all the compile time has increased at-least 40%.

Now I am looking at alternate framework and think log4cplus and logog seems fill all my requirements. Wanted to get an expert opinion on which would suit the above criteria rather than getting in a soup again after using the library for some time.

Comment: I don't know too much about it, but have you looked at [Boost's logger](http://boost-log.sourceforge.net/libs/log1/doc/html/index.html)?

Comment: Do you have troubles with 1st or 2nd version of boost.log?

Comment: Is there a 2nd version of boost log?? This is the version I am using http://boost-log.sourceforge.net/libs/log/doc/html/index.html

Comment: There are 2 versions of boost.log, both are authored by Andrey. First version is the old one which has been "stable" for quite a while. And the main link on sourceforge was to v1. I'm not sure what version is downloaded by default from the sourceforge.net now because I always download v2 from svn. Lately Andrey made another proposition for boost.log inclusion to official boost distribution(v2). And as far as I can tell it will be approved soon.

Comment: Seems like default link on sourceforge still pointing to v1(1.1)

Comment: There are at least log4cxx, log4cpp, and log4cplus ― have you looked into any of these?

Comment: "No way to implicitly mention which module is logging" - if you want it implicit, you need to think about how the scopes will be implied.  You could use `#define MODULE xyz` throughout your source, and create a frontend macro to almost any logging information to supply that extra field...?  Similarly, you could have a global variable overridden by various namespace, class static or function scoped variables of the same name.  Pros and cons to everything but as is your needs are communicated in the question.